# Why is a paragraph rendering inside my navbar?

Tags: html, css

EDIT: I added the CSS to show what I mean. I'm trying to create a website to detail information for a friend's server they have for this literature community he has, but cant seem to get the writing to lay on the purple part of the website, not the black part (the nav bar)

I am confused as to why the paragraph is spawning inside the navbar I have made? I'm new at coding. Any help would be appreciated!

I'm not sure what exactly I have to do because I don't understand why its spawning in the navbar.

```css
html,
body {
  font-family: 'Cinzel Decorative', cursive;
  text-align: center;
  background: #543DAF;
}

body {
  padding-bottom: 56px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #30302F;
}

li,
a,
button {
  font-family: "Cinzel Decorative";
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #F4DA65;
  text-decoration: none;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px 10%;
}

.logo {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  right: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.nav_links {
  list-style: none;
}

.nav_links li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 100px;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  right: 100px;
}

#Btn1 {
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 5px;
}

#Btn2 {
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 5px;
}

#Btn3 {
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 5px;
}

#Btn4 {
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 5px;
}

#Btn5 {
  padding: 9px 25px;
  background: rgba(84, 61, 175, 1);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  margin-right: 50px;
  position: relative;
  left: 80px;
}

#Btn5:hover {
  background: rgba(84, 61, 175, 0.8);
}


/* Dropdown Button */

.dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  position: relative;
}


/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}


/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  margin-right: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #30302F min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Links inside the dropdown */

.dropdown-content a {
  color: #F4DA65;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}


/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(84, 61, 175, 0.8);
  ;
}


/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cinzel+Decorative&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <a href="https://athra.wiki"><img class="logo" src="athralogo.png" alt="Alogo" height="40px" width="80px"></a>

    <nav>
      <ul class="nav_links">
        <div class="dropdown">
          <li><a href="#"><button class="dropbtn" id="Btn1">Lore</button></a></li>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="PrimordialEra.html">The Primordial Era</a>
            <a href="#">The Dawn Era</a>
            <a href="#">The Second Era</a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="dropdown">
          <li><a href="#"><button class="dropbtn" id="Btn2">Info</button></a></li>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Characters</a>
            <a href="#">World</a>
            <a href="#">Magic</a>
            <a href="#">Races</a>
            <a href="#">Religion</a>
            <a href="#">Gods</a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="dropdown">
          <li><a href="#"><button class="dropbtn" id="Btn3">Resources</button></a></li>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Beastiary</a>
            <a href="#">Maps</a>
            <a href="#">War System</a>
            <a href="#">Spells List </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <a class="cta" href="#"><button id="Btn5" onclick="window.location.href='https://discord.gg/XtEDk7S8ax'">Roleplay Server</button></a>
  </header>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <div class="P1">
    <p>Welcome, fellow travellers! To Athra: Age of Kings</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Your [list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul) markup has invalid structure. Divs are not allowed child elements. The browser will attempt to correct that and other errors. Please run your markup through an HTML validator or use a good editor.

Comment: That said, I don't see what you're describing. There are no paragraph elements in the rendered output of this markup.

Answer (score 0):

I went through and validated your markup. Please take note of the changes to prevent potential semantical browser issues in the future.

The `p` is not inside the navbar. You set `* { background: #30302F;}` which sets this background-color on all elements. The navbar happens to have the same `background` so it appears as if it is inside the navbar. `.P1` also has this `background` so the color needs to be changed on that div also. See adjustments in the CSS.

```css
html,
body {
  font-family: 'Cinzel Decorative', cursive;
  text-align: center;
  background: #543DAF;
}

body {
  padding-bottom: 56px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #30302F; /* problematic */
}

li,
a,
button {
  font-family: "Cinzel Decorative";
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #F4DA65;
  text-decoration: none;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px 10%;
}

.logo {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  right: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.nav_links {
  list-style: none;
}

.nav_links li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 100px;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  right: 100px;
}

#Btn1 {
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 5px;
}

#Btn2 {
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 5px;
}

#Btn3 {
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 5px;
}

#Btn4 {
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 5px;
}

#Btn5 {
  padding: 9px 25px;
  background: rgba(84, 61, 175, 1);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  margin-right: 50px;
  position: relative;
  left: 80px;
}

#Btn5:hover {
  background: rgba(84, 61, 175, 0.8);
}


/* Dropdown Button */

.dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  position: relative;
}


/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}


/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  margin-right: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #30302F min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Links inside the dropdown */

.dropdown-content a {
  color: #F4DA65;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}


/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(84, 61, 175, 0.8);
  ;
}


/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

/* remove background-color on p */

.P1,
.P1 > p {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cinzel+Decorative&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <a href="https://athra.wiki"><img class="logo" src="athralogo.png" alt="Alogo" height="40px" width="80px"></a>
    <nav>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <a href="#"><button class="dropbtn" id="Btn1">Lore</button></a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="PrimordialEra.html">The Primordial Era</a>
          <a href="#">The Dawn Era</a>
          <a href="#">The Second Era</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <a href="#"><button class="dropbtn" id="Btn2">Info</button></a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Characters</a>
          <a href="#">World</a>
          <a href="#">Magic</a>
          <a href="#">Races</a>
          <a href="#">Religion</a>
          <a href="#">Gods</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <a href="#"><button class="dropbtn" id="Btn3">Resources</button></a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Beastiary</a>
          <a href="#">Maps</a>
          <a href="#">War System</a>
          <a href="#">Spells List </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <a class="cta" href="#"><button id="Btn5" onclick="window.location.href='https://discord.gg/XtEDk7S8ax'">Roleplay Server</button></a>
  </header>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <div class="P1">
    <p>Welcome, fellow travellers! To Athra: Age of Kings</p>
  </div>
</body>
```